# Accessing a lower layers fields with lambda function in Scapy

Tags: python, layer, scapy

I want to do something like the following

```
class Upper(Packet):

    name = "UpperLayer"
    fields_desc = [
        ConditionalField(IntField("Field",0xABCDEF00),
                         lambda pkt: pkt[IP].src == "1.2.3.4")
                   ]

p = IP(src="1.2.3.4")/Upper()
```

But this does not work - I assume because the upper layer `Upper` has no information about the lower `IP` layer and therefore cannot access the `src` field. But it is necessary for me to access a value stored in a lower layer. In a protocol which I'm trying to implement exactly this is needed. So how could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lower- or leftbound layer is called `underlayer`. Here's what you're searching for:

```
class Upper(Packet):
    name = "UpperLayer"
    fields_desc = [
        ConditionalField(IntField("Field",0xABCDEF00),
                         lambda pkt: hasattr(pkt.underlayer,"src") and pkt.underlayer.src == "1.2.3.4")
                   ]
```